# 配列の４の倍数目の要素が空かどうか調べたい

Tags: java, jsp, servlet

配列の４の倍数目の要素が空かどうか調べたいです。

リスト＜リスト＜ストリング＞＞型の csvResult　の配列の４の倍数目の要素が空かどうか調べたく、

```
 for(int i = 4; i < csvResult.size(); i++) {
                if (null != csvResult.get(i)) {
                    for (int j = 0; j < csvResult.get(i).size(); j++) {
                        System.out.println("csvResult"+csvResult.get(i).get(j));
                        if(csvResult.get(i) /4 != null){
                            itemDao = new T001ItemDao();
                            int itembean = itemDao.update(code, name, unitPrice, count);
                            request.setAttribute("itembean", itembean);
                            nextPage = "/list.jsp";
                        }else{
                            int result = itemDao.addItem(name, unitPrice, count,isPR,img);
                            if (result == 1) {
                                nextPage = "/list.jsp";
                            } else {
                                nextPage = "/add.jsp";
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
```

と書きました。
しかし、  `if(csvResult.get(i) /4 != null)`
の部分で　演算子 / は引数の型 List, int で未定義です　とエラーが出てしまいました。どのように書けば正しく処理が行えるでしょうか？

ちなみに、４の倍数目の要素が空かどうかでデータベースへの登録処理を変えたいです。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'i'はインデックスですから、'i'で判断して良いと思います。

```
if (0 == (i % 4))
```